# UWP TimePicker SelectedTimeChanged Doesn't exist

Tags: xaml, uwp

According to this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.timepicker.selectedtimechanged

The UWP TimePicker has a SelectedTimeChange Event but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just `TimeChanged` This must either be an older API or a typo. **(edit: Turns out it's a newer API. Details below)**

```
<TimePicker TimeChanged="TimePicker_TimeChanged" />

private void TimePicker_TimeChanged(object sender, TimePickerValueChangedEventArgs e) { }

public event EventHandler<TimePickerValueChangedEventArgs> TimeChanged
```

Edit:  It looks like a typo.  I've added an issue on GitHub for it.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/winrt-api/issues/853

Edit to the Edit:

A response on GitHub as quoted by 'jwmsft':

> @MichaelPuckett2, the SelectedTimeChanged event is new in Windows 10,
>   version 1809 (SDK 17763). Your project needs to target this version to
>   use this event.
>
> This should be shown on the event's doc page, but a
>   bug in the doc generation system is preventing that right now. A fix
>   is being worked on.

I tried to reference 1809 from Visual Studio 2017 and couldn't.  I was able to reference it in Visual Studio 2019 Preview.  However; after referencing it in VS2019PV I could see the API and also save / see it in VS2017 but I have not been able to complete a build with that target and those changes made.  *Shrugs*